# Efficient way to to close android app at particular time of interval

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to close my app in a particular time interval according to users selection.

so i what i did is i display a list of time interval and according to that list item selected i pass that to handler and runnable and post-delay method.
Can anybody knows different and efficient way to exit at particular time from app.

Here is my code

```
setContentView(R.layout.audio_player);
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
      lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
     lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.testxml, lv_arr));
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
        //  final TextView mTextView = (TextView)view;
          switch (position) {
            case 0:
                j=2;
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(Play.this, "2 min selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                 t.show();
              break;
            case 1:
                j=5;
                Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(Play.this, "5 min selected ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                 t1.show();    break;

            case 2:
                j=10;
                Toast t2 = Toast.makeText(Play.this, "10 min selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                 t2.show();    break;

            case 3:
                j=15;
                Toast t3 = Toast.makeText(Play.this, "15 min selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                 t3.show();    
        break;
            default:
              // Nothing do!
          }

      }
    });
    try {
        mp.setDataSource("http://94.55.45.123/bbc");
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            mp.start();
 b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handler=new Handler();
            final Runnable r = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() 
                {

                        myFinish();
                }
            };

            handler.postDelayed(r, (60*1000)+j);
             i++;
        }
        private void myFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(Play.this, "Music stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         t1.show();
        mp.stop();
         finish();
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
         intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
         startActivity(intent);
        }


    });

}
```

Comment: Hello friends..just tell me is it efficient way or not?

Answer (score 0):

Typically for short delays using the `postDelayed()` approach you have is good enough.

I am not sure if there is a rule but typically over for delays over 5 minutes I would use the `AlarmManager`.